# Changing date.format in R

Tags: r, date

So let's imagine I have a vector containing dates :

```
vec <- c(11993, 21993, 31993, 41993)
```

How can I effectively transform it into a vector containg quarterly dates :

```
vec <- c(T1 1993, T2 1993, T3 1993, T4 1993)
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output? Should `vec` contain strings or some datetime object? The result you provide is not correct R syntax.

Comment: well any data formet would suit me, I'm new to R unfortunately

Comment: If what you want is a character vector (strings), this does what you want: `sub("(\\d)", "T\\1 ", vec)`. It looks for the first digit and replaces it with itself, with a T prepended and a space appended. It uses something called a 'regular expression', which is a whole language on its own.

Comment: Is your vector really numeric? Your second vector (`c(T1 1993, T2 1993)`) suggests that these might be strings instead (since that is obviously not legal code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

quarter <- paste0("T",str_sub(vec, start = 1L, end = 1L))
vec <- paste0(quarter, " ",str_sub(vec, start = 2L))
```

Which gives you:

```
"T1 1993" "T2 1993" "T3 1993" "T4 1993"
```

Update:

You can use the `zoo` package to convert to type `yearqtr`:

```
vec_date <- as.yearqtr(vec, format = "T%q %Y")
```

Which gives us:

```
"1993 Q1" "1993 Q2" "1993 Q3" "1993 Q4"
```

You can also include `as.Date`:

```
vec_date <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(vec, format = "T%q %Y"))
```

Which gives us:

```
"1993-01-01" "1993-04-01" "1993-07-01" "1993-10-01"
```

Everything together:

```
library(zoo)
library(tidyverse)

# Your vector
vec <- c(11993, 21993, 31993, 41993)

# Substring to create "T" values
quarter <- paste0("T",str_sub(vec, start = 1L, end = 1L))

# Paste back together
vec <- paste0(quarter, " ",str_sub(vec, start = 2L))

# Keep as yearqtr 
vec_date <- as.yearqtr(vec, format = "T%q %Y")

# Keep as.Date
vec_date <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(vec, format = "T%q %Y"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry if I was not clear but I would like to actually transform "11993" in a valid date format so I can plot it as a x-axis. The "T1 1993" was just to illustrate what seemed to me as a valid format but apparently it is not because R says it is non standard.

Comment: What is valid about `11993` as a class `Date`? Perhaps better asked ... it's not `Date`, so is it always the quarter-year or month-year?

Comment: It is always quarter year in my dataset

Comment: Odd, your `as.yearqtr(vec, format = "T%q %y")` does not seem to honor the format (on my console). I'm on zoo-1.8.7, and while 1.8.8 is available, it doesn't list any changes there. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm using zoo-1.8.7 as well. What do you mean about not honoring the format? I should have noted that using `as.Date` converts the quarters to the earliest month/year for the quarter, so we get: `"2019-01-01" "2019-04-01" "2019-07-01" "2019-10-01"`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was using the raw `vec`, not the modified/`quarter`-ized `vec`. On the numeric version, `as.yearqtr(vec, format="...")` did not use `format=`, it returned `"11993 Q1"`, indicating my mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your extended answer. I am sorry but I am still missing out something here. When I run in console the following code https://pastebin.com/20K0xFJY (with my longer initial vector), I get a vector with only dates from 2019 to 2020 which is not coherent with my initial dataset.

Comment: I just edited the answer - I made a mistake and used a lowercase `y`. You need to have `format = "T%q %Y` with an uppercase `Y`.

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```r
sub("^(.*)(.{4})$", "T\\1 \\2", vec)
# [1] "T1 1993" "T2 1993" "T3 1993" "T4 1993"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution without regex

```
paste0("T", substr(vec, 1, 1), " ", substr(vec, 2, 5))
# [1] "T1 1993" "T2 1993" "T3 1993" "T4 1993"
```